# Using xaml page on codebehind

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have some Viewbox xaml pages which have no codebehind.
I want to load it as a object, clone it and combine them to make more complex visual. But I have no idea about loading a xaml page from code. What's the efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: If you have a code-less XAML page, you will need to do what otherwise the implementation of the `InitializeComponent` method would do. Create a new page (you can delete it again later) with code-behind, and inspect the `InitializeComponent` method (called in the constructor) to see what your code has to do to instantiate and initialize your code-less XAML markup class.

Comment: @elgonzo I got it. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

[XamlReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader(v=vs.110).aspx) can be used to read XAML input and creates an object graph.

You can find an example from [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ashish/2007/08/14/dynamically-loading-xaml/).